Why does "ß".Equals("SS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) differ between Net 4.8 and 6.0?
The following code behaves differently between .NET 4.8 and .NET 6.0 with 4.8 behaving as I'd expect (see also Why is "ss" equal to the German sharp-s character 'ß'?)
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-de");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-de");
var eq = "ß".Equals("SS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); 
// True in .NET 4.8 
// False in .NET 6.0


At a guess I’d say because in the meantime Unicode added a capital-eszett code point (U+1E9E ẞ). Though by standard German orthography rules the two should still compare (or at least sort) identically, so I’d consider this a bug in .NET 6.0.

@Konard I thought so too, but the current case folding rules still say that small ß should map to ss as far as I can see: 00DF; F; 0073 0073; # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S (https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/CaseFolding.txt)

Perhaps because of this change?

It's because they started using ICU in .NET 5 and later: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/globalization-icu

@Matthew And ICU is simply incorrect here? That's very surprising, I'd usually expect it to be more accurate than MS's homegrown solution, but from my understanding the original behavior is correct.

I would say there is no such thing as a "correct" result here. Locale-sensitive string comparison is never so black-and-white that a bool is enough to represent the result. But of course, it has to be a bool at the end of the day, so different libraries choose the result to be true or false based on various different factors. Either result is not surprising to me.

@Sweeper Yes and no. Of course you can define various, meaningful conventions. But the Unicode standard defines a canonical mapping rule for this character, and ICU is seemingly non-compliant by violating that rule.

@Sweeper The ICU result is very surprising to me because it not only violates the Unicode standard as far as I can tell, but also standard German orthography rules. I don't see much grey here.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but while you can replace the ß with ss, it does not always work the other way around. As example; massstab may be equal to maßstab, but not masßtab.

@Matthew If you want to just post that as an answer, I'll accept it. I'll post a follow-up question though, why ICU behaves the way it does.

Follow-up question as promised: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78371156/%c3%9f-ss-for-case-insensitive-comparison-with-icu Curious to see if anyone can explain this.

@Voo you can check the ICU docs. It seems that searching should treat ß and ss the same, but not equal. This isn't explicitly mentioned though, and searching for ß in Chrome and Edge matches ss, making things rather difficult. The regular expression page shows that ß should match ss in a regex

@Voo it's easier to search in Github because it matches ß exactly.

@Panagiotis IndexOf also shows the same behavior as Equals (i.e. "Straße".IndexOf("SS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == -1). The two behaving differently would be particularly weird to me, but then Unicode is confusing.

IndexOf isn't exactly a search. But both Contains and Regex.IsMatch fail

It's because they started using ICU in .NET 5 and later:

This resulted in some behavioral differences in a handful of
globalization APIs when running applications on different platforms

There is more information about the differences here.
You can prove that this is what caused the change by reverting to the old NLS library by adding the following to your project file:
<ItemGroup>
  <RuntimeHostConfigurationOption Include="System.Globalization.UseNls" Value="true" />
</ItemGroup>

After adding that and recompiling, the comparison will return true for .NET 5 or later instead of false.
