ß != ss for case insensitive comparison with ICU
The following C# code returns false when using .NET 6 which uses the ICU library for its string comparisons:
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-de");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("de-de");
"ß".Equals("SS", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);  // false with ICU

From my understanding this should be true based on the Unicode case folding rules (and also - somewhat more importantly - standard German orthographic rules):
00DF; F; 0073 0073; # LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S (CaseFolding.txt)
When using the legacy Microsoft NLS implementation, the above code returns true.
So why does the ICU library used by .NET 6 differ from the Unicode standard or is my understanding of the standard incorrect here?
Original C# question that lead to this.

That's a statement. What is the question here?

@Fildor "From my understanding this should be true based on the Unicode case folding rules", but I can make it a bit clearer to avoid misunderstandings.

It is unclear what kind of answer you want to get out of a "why" question like this. This is better suited to be a bug report for ICU, than a stack overflow question.

.NET 6 doesn't use a special ICU implementation. It's ICU itself that behaves differently. The docs specify that ß should match ss in searches and regex but say nothing about equality

@Sweeper That presumes that this is a bug and not a misunderstanding of the spec on my part. The answer could very well be "paragraph X of the latest spec says this is acceptable behavior"

Whether it is a bug or not doesn't really matter. Lots of tickets get resolved with "not an issue" or "by design" or the like. My point is that you are likely to get better responses by submitting a bug report, rather than posting a Stack Overflow question.

@Sweeper this is a valid question, affecting quite a lot of people. And according to the ICU string search docs, "Heisse".Contains("ß") should work. German rules weren't created yesterday, nor is German a minor market. When Microsoft talked about "localized" in the past it meant just French, German and Spanish.  This could be a bug, or could require different coding.

In fact, the docs explicitly mention pattern “ß” will find occurrences of “ss” or “ß”. as an example

So, I take this as "is this a bug or am I missing something"... I really do think Sweeper and Panagiotis have a point each. On one hand, it might be insightful to get a response to an accordingly worded bug report, on the other hand it would be nice if somebody (on SO) already has an answer and practical solution - bug or not.

As an example, if I search for ß on this page, it also matches all the SS instances (in Edge).

^^ Oddly enough, it doesn't in a Firefox on a German Windows 10.

That's... Even weirder

Matches on Chrome, Brave, ...

The ICU test tool compares them also as expected. Feels like that the ICU library is correctly behaving but there is something wrong/missing/misunderstood in the usage of it in the framework.

@Ralf That's a great tool, bookmarked it for future use. So it seems that a bug report for Microsoft is in order now that I have a grasp of the problem. Let's see what they say.

I created an issue with the dotnet repo now that we've probably isolated the issue. Let's see what comes of it.

Unicode is complicated.
Turns out the behavior is intentional. See this Github issue on the matter where tarekgh summarizes the issue:

ICU collation work using what it is called collation strength.
Strength can be Primary, Secondary, Tertiary, or Quaternary. We are
trying to map as much as we can the .NET comparison options to one of
these strength. which work fine except in such special cases.
Unfortunately, ICU make ß equals only to ss if having the ICU strength
is primary. We cannot switch to that strength by default in .NET
because is going to break many other things.

The default collation strength used by .NET is tertiary and secondary for case insensitive comparisons (as far as I can tell from code).
The workaround is to use StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace | CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) - the CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace forces a primary collation strength in which case ß and ss will compare equal.
There are probably a few unintended side effects from that switch but at least the German speakers will be happy.

Upvoted, saved and bookmarked. Most valuable Q&A. Would +2 if I could.

As this answer indicates, the comparison is based on collation weights, not on casefolded strings. Case distinctions in UCA occurs at a tertiary strength. The differnece between ß and ss does not occur at a tertiary strength, but rather at a secondary strength, as per relevant DIN standards. So Case insensitivity,  which bumps the collation strength form tertiary to secondary would not impact on the difference between the collation weights of ß and ss.
